# copy char* array in local variable

Tags: c++, pointers

C++ newbie.

I have following class and its argument is `char*`, 
How do I copy that to member variable `char*` ?
After that I need to know the size of array ?

```
class TestParam {

public:
  char*[] arr;
  TestParam (const char* Pre, char* Post[]){
    arr = Post;
  }
};
....
TestParam testParam[1] = { TestParam ("aa", (char*[]){"bb","cc","dd"})};
```

I know about std::string but I had to use `char*` because I am initializing the object like above in my code. Is it possible by std::string ?

Comment: You won't be able to know the size of any array if all you have is a pointer to the first element. I suggest using user defined types instead of raw pointers and pointers to pointers.

Comment: First read about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), then read about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: "char* which is array of strings" - Not accurate.

Comment: There are many things wrong here, but the one that stands out is how to you know how many strings you have in your Post array? Until you know the answer to that question you can't begin to address the other problems. As others have said, the easy answer is std::vector and std::string. Trust us, it might seem like yet another new thing to learn about, but it will be much much simpler in the long run.

Comment: @john the number of strings in Post array are going to be fixed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have updated why i have used char*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need the number of elements in `Post` - that needs to be passed in as another argument, unless `Post` is defined to have a NULL last element, in which case you need to count the non-NULL elements first.

Once you know that, you can allocate memory for `arr`.

Finally, you can either perform a shallow copy by assigning the pointer values (eg. `arr[i] = Post[i]`, or a deep copy by duplicating each string. You haven't told us which you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate sufficient memory to the destination pointer and then use `std::copy`.

Tip: Consider using `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a solution where you use `std::string` and `std::vector` instead, like this:

```
class TestParam {
public:
    std::vector<std::string> arr;

    TestParam (const std::string& Pre, const std::vector<std::string>& Post){
        arr = Post;
    }
};

...

TestParam testParam[1] = { TestParam ("aa", {"bb","cc","dd"})};
```

Comment: Its giving 'no matching function for call to TestParam::TestParam(const char [3], <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'.... Do I need to typecast it to (std::vector) ?

Comment: @VijayC It shouldn't be needed. What compiler (and version of it) are you using?

Comment: I am using g++ on ubuntu

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: @VijayC Try adding the `-std=c++11` (or if you have an older version `-std=c++0x`) option when building.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestParam {
    public:
    template <std::size_t N>
    TestParam(const char* pre, const char* (&arr_ref)[N]) {
        arr.reserve(N);
        for(const char* p: arr_ref) {
            if(p) arr.push_back(std::string(p));
        }
    }
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
};

int main() {
    const char* a[] = { "Hello", " " , "World" };
    TestParam param((char*)0, a);
    for(const std::string& s: param.arr) std::cout << s;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```